# I can't see AdMob ads and test ads

Tags: android, admob, ads

I'm beginner on android studio, I created my first app and I used AdMob test ads but nothing is shown, I tried with real ads and nothing too. I searched everywhere for a solution and I tried different codes but always nothing.

**manifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.blogspot.bepro_ar.babyphoneanimalssounds">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

**Here is the Main Activity XML**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" />
```

I tried also with real ads with a test device.

**LangActivity.java**

```
package com.blogspot.bepro_ar.babyphoneanimalssounds;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class LangActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AdView mAdView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lang);

    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(),
            "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX");

    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.addd);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

My app on Play Store [Baby Phone Animals Sounds](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blogspot.bepro_ar.babyphoneanimalssounds&hl=fr)

Comment: Any errors? If not, wait for it. Sometimes it takes some time to load the ads.

Comment: There are no errors, i waited about 15 minutes and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file, add

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

to your relativeLayout. This helps the xml identify what the Adview is and does.

Also, your findViewById code is wrong. The id is "adView2" not "addd". ie replace

```
mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.addd);
```

with

```
mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView2);
```

Comment: I already using this code in my xml file.
These id are correct, in Main Activity the id is called "adView2" 
the other activity (Lang Activity) i pute another adview "addd"

Comment: Oh I see. Hmm the code you've posted is otherwise okay. Perhaps double check that the string you've copied from Admob website in your specific app is correct.

Comment: Yes it's correct, also the test ads string is correct